# Why does my Intel XDK Crosswalk for Android-exported app not open?

Tags: android, intel, intel-xdk, construct

After using Intel XDK to export my created Construct 2 game (CAPX) to Crosswalk for Android (APK), it seemed that it won't even open.

This is the error message I get:

[enter link description here](http://dropbox.com/s/ypctwdkl49tirq4/x86error.png?dl=0)

Comment: The ADB logcat output would be helpful. Please follow this [guide](http://university.utest.com/android-debug-bridge-part-1-how-to-capture-logcat-files-using-adb/) to capture the logcat output and post it here.

Comment: Try running your app using the Debug tab. The Debug tab will run your app inside a Crosswalk WebView, just like your build, and it will give you a full Chrome DevTools console to work with.

Comment: Hi Alexander and xmnboy, I don't quite understand, sorry.

Comment: Hi Alexander, here are the logcats I got: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vbasj5ki0fxqml4/ellowoyld.txt?dl=0 , https://www.dropbox.com/s/merhavd6eocs7xw/20152801120200-logcat.txt?dl=0 . Any solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

check your CPU architecture (arm or x86) crosswalk contain 2 files 1 for arm processor and the other for x86  install the right for you .
i have a tablet with arm processor when i install x86 it gives me same error message.

download an app called cpuz if  want more details about your device

Comment: Hi skywalker, I already did that. This is the error for the ARM APK: https://www.dropbox.com/s/px5jtpkrftk04p2/ARMerror.png?dl=0 . Any other solution please?